# Issue connecting root with mysql_config_editor inside of Ubuntu server

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I recently tried to get my server hooked up with mysql_config_editor.  I added the server to the .cnf file with `mysql_config_editor set --login-path=FailOverTest --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --password`.

However, when I try to run the command `sudo mysqlserverinfo --se                                           rver=FailOverTest --format=vertical`, it gives me the error `ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' using password: YES`.

I know the password is correct, because if I run mysql -uroot -p, it connects me to the shell as root, and I have double checked the port is correct inside of the servers my.cnf file.

I have tried switching the host around.  localhost, 0.0.0.0, and the server IP all return the same error.  I checked inside of the users database as well, and set it up so that root could be accessed from any server location as well, and not just localhost (although this shouldnt be the issue because I am running these commands from localhost).

Do you guys have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On your phpmyadmin main page you must have a menu for privileges, inside you have a list of users for your sql database, by default you have "root" you can add more access to this user or create a custom one.

Comment: One of my tests was creating custom users and seeing if it could connect with them.  I had a slave server and it would successfully connect with the same login credentials I was trying and getting an access denied for.

Comment: I'm almost sure the solution is there, I met the same issur this afternoon, I created a new user and gave it full access, the error disappeard

Comment: Its also just two different ubuntu servers, so I don't think I have phpmyadmin running on them.  They arent web servers.  When I did the same type of solution just by adding the users to the mysql users table and granting all permissions.